# How to reliably return focus to input box after blur() event?

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to process some input in a text box upon the blur() event. What I cannot seem to accomplish is returning the cursor to the text box if the text is not correct. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/zy5mv/

This works fine in IE (focus/cursor returns to the text box), but not Firefox or Chrome, where the focus us not returned. What am I doing wrong here? I've tried both the jQuery focus() method and the element's own focus() method.

Comment: Seems the focus is there in safari (there is a blue bounding box), but it isn't active for some reason. Strange

Comment: As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zy5mv/5/) the focus event is triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
   if(this.value != "ok") {
        //alert("Wrong answer");
        ev.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() { $('input').focus(); }, 100);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Gah, didn't even think to try that! If all else fails, try a timeout. :) Thanks!

Comment: This is working fine till I play withing browser window, but as I click outside of the browser, it continuously starts checking for that cont. and start focusing. what is solution for it?